# How to use click function as toggle

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery 1.3.2 (can't update because of drupal6)

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var textcontent = $('.trig').text();

  $('.trig').click(function() {
    if (textcontent == 'Open') {
      $(this).text('Close').addClass('not-trig');
    } else if (textcontent == 'Close') {
      $(this).text('Open');
    }
  })
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="trig">Open</div>
```

What i'm trying to do:

When you click on div with class .trig it should change the text "OPEN" to "close" and vice versa when you click again. But it seems like click works only once, when i click first time it changes the text from "Open" to "close" but when i click again - nothing happens...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to re-fetch the value of `var textcontent = $('.trig').text();` in every click

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.trig').click(function() {
        var textcontent = $('.trig').text();
        if (textcontent == 'Open') {
            $(this).text('Close').addClass('not-trig');
        } else if (textcontent == 'Close') {
            $(this).text('Open');
        }
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Jfxqb/1/)

Another clean implementation might be to look for the class `not-trig`, because it looks like you need the class only if it is `close`. ie if the text is `Open` then `not-trig` might have to be removed

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.trig').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if($this.hasClass('not-trig')){
            $this.text('Open').removeClass('not-trig');
        } else {
            $this.text('Close').addClass('not-trig');
        }
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cSPGN/2/)

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that... where i can read about that?

Comment: Thanks again, can you help me one more time, for example when you first click it expands down (with slide effect) the div to height 100%, then when you press again it returns div for example to 300px back.